# Custom Directive: passed in ng-model comes back null

Tags: angularjs

By all my logic this should work so I'm not sure what's going on. I'm trying to abstract out the datepicker into a custom directive. It is meant to replace this:

```
            <p class="input-group">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="yyyy-MM-dd" ng-model="modal.modalObject.start_date" is-open="modal.parentCtrl.opened['start']" min-date="'1920-01-01'" max-date="'2015-06-22'" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
              <span class="input-group-btn">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="modal.parentCtrl.open($event,'start')"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
              </span>
            </p>
```

So here's the directive/controller code:

```
.directive('datePicker', function () {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        ngmodel: '='
      },
      replace: true,
      controller: 'datepickerCtrl',
      controllerAs: 'ctrl',
      templateUrl: 'templates/datepicker.html'
    };
}).controller('datepickerCtrl',function ($scope) {
    this.opened = false;
    var _this = this;
    this.open = function($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        _this.opened = true;
    };
    this.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    this.format = 'MM/dd/yyyy';
    this.maxDate = new Date();
    this.minDate = new Date('1/1/1900');
});
```

Here's the template:

```
<p class="input-group datepicker">
  <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="MM/dd/yyyy" ng-model="ngmodel" is-open="ctrl.opened" datepicker-options="ctrl.dateOptions" min-date="minDate" close-text="Close" placeholder="mm/dd/yyyy"/>
    <span class="input-group-btn" ng-click="ctrl.open($event)">
        <button type="button" class="btn" ng-click="ctrl.open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
    </span>
</p>


<date-picker model="model.modalObject.end_date"></date-picker>
```

As I understand it, passing in `model="model.modalObject.end_date"` should make model available at the scope level, when I do `scope: model: '='` but it always returns 00/00/0000, the code i'm looking to replace works fine. Please help. Thanks!